# How to refresh the jsp page after a given time(or interval)?

Tags: java, jsp

I would like to refresh/reload my jsp page after a certain time interval.
Consider the time interval is of 5 minutes.

How can achieve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `public void setIntHeader(String header, int headerValue)`

```
response.setIntHeader("Refresh",300)
```

> This method sends back header "Refresh" to the browser along with an integer value which indicates time interval in seconds.

Comment: Setting which header?

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti do up vote or accept the answer if it helped

Answer (score 7):

You can try to add this:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="10">
```

So this will refresh the page every 10 seconds

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use javascript to do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  setTimeout(function(){
    location = ''
  },60*1000)
</script>
```

`setTimeout` will reload the page after a specified number of milliseconds, hence 60 * 1000 = 1m.

Answer (score 1):

In jsp add

```
<%
  response.setIntHeader("Refresh", time_in_second); //in your case 60*5=300 (for 5 min)
%>
```

If you want to do it without using java code then `Rahul Tripathi` solution is the best as html tag will work perfectly in jsp.

Comment: well then use the snipped code given in the answer.