# response.setIntHeader() is not refreshing my jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, struts-1

I need to conditionally set my jsp page to refresh and thought I had found the answer at  [Refresh JSP Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29741026/how-to-refresh-the-jsp-page-after-a-given-timeor-interval).  I tried using `response.setIntHeader("Refresh",10);` on my action page and it did not work so I tried using it directly on my `Jsp` page as shown below and it still didn't work.  This is a `Struts1` project.

```
<%@ taglib uri="/tags/struts-html" prefix="html"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/tags/struts-logic" prefix="logic"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/tags/struts-bean" prefix="bean"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/tlds/struts-nested.tld" prefix="nested"%>

<html:form action="/permit/permittedFeatureList" >
<html:xhtml/>
<-- lots of code goes here -->    

    <% response.setIntHeader("Refresh",10); %>

</html:form>
```

When I replace the `response.setIntHeader("Refresh",10);` with `<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="10">` the page refreshes.  I would prefer to use the Java code on the action page, does anyone have an idea as to why it isn't working?  Thanks!

**EDIT:**
`rupinderjeet47` asked me to show all of my code so here it is.

```
        <%@ page import="gov.mo.dnr.cwis.controller.system.permits.permittedFeature.PermittedFeatureListAction" %>
    <%@ page import="java.util.Map" %>
    <%@ page import="gov.mo.dnr.cwis.vo.ref.permit.PermitTypeInfo" %>
    <%@ page import="gov.mo.dnr.utilities.CodeTableConstants.PermitType" %>
    <%@ page import="gov.mo.dnr.utilities.CodeTableConstants.PermitStatus" %>
    <%@ taglib uri="/tags/struts-html" prefix="html"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="/tags/struts-logic" prefix="logic"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="/tags/struts-bean" prefix="bean"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="/tags/DNRTags" prefix="DNRTags"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/tlds/struts-nested.tld" prefix="nested"%>



    <%@page import="gov.mo.dnr.utilities.CodeTableConstants.PermitType"%><script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function loadMgpPf() 
    {
        document.permittedFeatureListForm.uglyJavaScriptHack.value="true";
        document.permittedFeatureListForm.submit();
    }
    </script>

    <DNRTags:checkLogon />
    <html:form action="/permit/permittedFeatureList" >
    <html:xhtml/>
    <% 
      Object permitInstanceIdpf = request.getParameter("permitInstanceId");
      if (permitInstanceIdpf == null) {
        permitInstanceIdpf = request.getAttribute("permitInstanceId");
      } if (permitInstanceIdpf == null) {
        Map navMap = (Map) request.getSession().getAttribute("permitNavMap");
        permitInstanceIdpf = Integer.parseInt(navMap.get("permitInstanceId").toString());
      }
      boolean permitStatus = false;
      request.setAttribute("pfHeader",PermittedFeatureListAction.getPermittedFeatureHeader(permitInstanceIdpf));
        java.util.Map<String,String>  pstatus = (java.util.Map<String,String>)request.getAttribute("pfHeader");

        if ( pstatus.get("permitStatus").equals(PermitStatus.DRAFT.status()))
        {permitStatus = true;}

      boolean gpcfFlag = false;
      PermitTypeInfo ptInfo = (PermitTypeInfo)(session.getAttribute("permitTypeInfo"));
      PermitType pt = PermitType.getPermitTypeById(ptInfo.getPermitTypeId());
      if (pt== PermitType.GPCF  || pt== PermitType.GPCF_CONST){
        gpcfFlag= true;
        } 


    %>
    <h2>
      <%if(gpcfFlag == true){ %>
          GPCF
      <% }%>
      Permitted Features List
    </h2>

    <h3 align="center">
      <bean:write scope="request" name="pfHeader" property="permitStatus" />
      <logic:equal scope="request" name="pfHeader" property="permitStatus" value="Draft" >
       &nbsp;-&nbsp; <bean:write scope="request" name="pfHeader" property="permitAction" />
      </logic:equal>
      <br />
      Permit ID: <bean:write scope="request" name="pfHeader" property="permitNo" /><br />
    </h3>
    <%@ include file="/WEB-INF/pages/system/permits/facility/underEnforcement.jspf"%>
    <%@ include file="/WEB-INF/pages/system/permits/messages.jspf" %>
    <div id="permitReadOnly">
      <table width="100%">
        <tr valign="top">
          <td width="25%">
            <fieldset>
              Facility ID: <bean:write scope="request" name="pfHeader" property="facilityId" /><br />
              Facility: <bean:write scope="request" name="pfHeader" property="facilityName" /><br />
              Owner Name: <bean:write scope="request" name="pfHeader" property="facilityOwner" /><br />
              County: <bean:write scope="request" name="pfHeader" property="countyName" /><br />
              Region: <bean:write scope="request" name="pfHeader" property="region" /><br />
            </fieldset>
          </td>
          <td width="25%">
            <fieldset>
              Permit Type: <bean:write scope="request" name="pfHeader" property="permitType" /><br />
              Non-NPDES Type: <bean:write scope="request" name="pfHeader" property="subType" /><br />
              Construction Type: <bean:write scope="request" name="pfHeader" property="conType" /><br />
              Initial Date: <bean:write scope="request" name="pfHeader" property="initialDate" /><br />
            </fieldset>
          </td>
          <td width="25%">
            <fieldset>
              Issue Date: <bean:write scope="request" name="pfHeader" property="issueDate" /><br />
              Effective Date: <bean:write scope="request" name="pfHeader" property="effDate" /><br />
              Expiration Date: <bean:write scope="request" name="pfHeader" property="expDate" /><br />
              Termination Date: <bean:write scope="request" name="pfHeader" property="termDate" /><br />
            </fieldset>
          </td>
          <td width="25%">
            <fieldset> 
              <%if(gpcfFlag == true){ %>
                  GPCF Version Number: <bean:write scope="request" name="pfHeader" property="gpcfVersion" /><br />
                  MGP Version Number: <bean:write scope="request" name="pfHeader" property="mgpVersion" /><br />
                  MGP Permit Name: <bean:write scope="request" name="pfHeader" property="mgpName" /><br />
               <%} %>
            </fieldset>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <%-- Add gpcf permitted feature --%>
    <DNRTags:AccessRoles roleList="System Administrator, Permit 1, Permit 2, Permit 3">
      <%if(gpcfFlag == true){ %>
          <div align="right">
            <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" class="dataEntryBorder">
              <tr>
                <td colspan="7" class="rowsecthead">GPCF Permitted Feature</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="97" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
                <td width="152" align="right"><span class="required">*</span><label for="permittedFeatureNo">No:</label></td>
                <td width="229" align="left">
                  <html:text property="permittedFeatureNo"  styleId="permittedFeatureNo" size="3" maxlength="3" />
                </td>
                <td width="26" class="columnseperator"></td>
                <td align="right"><span class="required">*</span><label for="activeDate">Active Date or Date Limit Sets Can Be Added:</label></td>
                <td  colspan="2" align="left" width="229">
                  <html:text property="activeDate" styleId="activeDate" size="10" maxlength="10" onblur="checkdate(activeDate);"/>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
                <td align="right">
                  <label for="mgpPermittedFeatureId">
                    <span class="required">*</span>MGP Permitted Features
                  </label>
                </td>
                <td align="left">
                <% request.setAttribute("mgpPfCodes",PermittedFeatureListAction.getMgpPfCodes(permitInstanceIdpf)); %>
                  <span class="borderbottom">
                    <html:hidden property="uglyJavaScriptHack" />
                    <html:select property="mgpPermittedFeatureId" styleId="mgpPermittedFeatureId" onchange=" loadMgpPf(); ">
                      <html:option value=""></html:option>
                      <html:options collection="mgpPfCodes" property="value" labelProperty="label" />
                    </html:select>
                  </span>
                </td>
                <td class="columnseperator"></td>
                <td align="right">Type Description:<br /></td>
                <td colspan="2" align="left">
                  <bean:write name="permittedFeatureListForm" property="typeDescription" />
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
                <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="columnseperator"></td>
                <td align="right">Waste Type:</td>
                <td colspan="2" align="left">
                  <bean:write name="permittedFeatureListForm" property="wasteType" />
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
                <td align="right" valign="top"><label for="comments">Comments: </label></td>
                <td align="left"><html:textarea property="comments" styleId="comments" cols="30" rows="3" /></td>
                <td class="columnseperator"></td>
                <td align="right" valign="top">Comments:</td>
                <td colspan="2" valign="top" align="left">
                  <bean:write name="permittedFeatureListForm" property="mgpPfComments" />
                </td>
               </tr>
              <logic:notEqual scope="request" name="pfHeader" property="permitStatus" value="Terminated" >
              <logic:notEqual scope="request" name="pfHeader" property="permitStatus" value="Retired" >
              <tr>
                <td colspan="7" align="center">
                  <html:submit property="action" styleClass="button" value="Add" alt="Add"
                      onmouseover="this.className='button buttonhov'" 
                      onmouseout="this.className='button'" />
                  <html:submit property="action" styleClass="button" value="Clear" alt="Clear" 
                      onmouseover="this.className='button buttonhov'" 
                      onmouseout="this.className='button'" />
                </td>
              </tr>
              </logic:notEqual>
              </logic:notEqual>
            </table>
          </div>
       <%} %>
    </DNRTags:AccessRoles>
    <div align="right">
    <logic:notPresent scope="request" name="dnr.mo.gov.permits.permittedFeatureList">
      <%
        try {
            PermittedFeatureListAction.reload(request);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
      %>
    </logic:notPresent>
    <logic:present scope="request" name="dnr.mo.gov.permits.permittedFeatureList">
    <%if(gpcfFlag == false){ %>
      <table width="100%" class="searchresults bordersingle" >
        <caption>Click on a Permitted Feature ID link below to view, edit, or delete the Permitted Feature.</caption>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th width="10%"><center>No.</center></th>
            <th width="15%" align="center">Primary Indicator</th>
            <th width="17%" align="center">Type</th>
            <th width="10%" align="center">Active</th>
            <th width="10%" align="center">Complete</th>
            <th width="18%" align="center">Mapped</th>
            <th width="20%" align="center">Trace Status</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <% int count = 0; %>
          <logic:iterate id="row" scope="request" name="dnr.mo.gov.permits.permittedFeatureList" property="permittedFeatureList" >
            <% if( count % 2 == 0 ) { %>
              <tr class="rowaltcolor">
            <% } else { %>
              <tr bgcolor="white">                                  
            <% } %> 
              <td align="center">
                <html:link action="/permit/permittedFeatureBasic" paramId="permittedFeatureId"
                    paramName="row" paramProperty="permittedFeatureId">
                  <bean:write name="row" property="permittedFeatureNum" />
                </html:link>
              </td>
              <td align="center">
                <label for="Permitted Feature ${row.selectedPrimaryId}" class="hidden">Primary Indicator</label>
                <html:radio idName="row" value="permittedFeatureId" property="selectedPrimaryId" styleId="Permitted Feature ${row.selectedPrimaryId}"/>
              </td>
              <td align="left">
                <bean:write name="row" property="permittedFeatureTypeDesc" />
              </td>
              <td align="center">
                <bean:write name="row" property="isActive" />
              </td>
              <td align="center">
                <bean:write name="row" property="isComplete" />
              </td>
              <td align="center">
                <bean:write name="row" property="isMapped" />
              </td>
              <td align="center">
                <bean:write name="row" property="permittedFeatureTraceStatus" />
              </td>
            </tr>
            <% count++; %>
          </logic:iterate>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    <%} %>
    <%if(gpcfFlag == true){ %>
      <table width="100%" class="searchresults bordersingle" >
        <caption>Click on a Permitted Feature ID link below to view, edit, or delete the Permitted Feature.</caption>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th width="10%" align="center">GPCF PF No.</th>
            <th width="15%" align="center">MGP PF No.</th>
            <th width="17%" align="center">Primary Indicator</th>
            <th width="15%" align="center">Type</th>
            <th width="10%" align="center">Active</th>
            <th width="10%" align="center">Complete</th>
            <th width="17%" align="center">Mapped</th>
            <th width="20%" align="center">Trace Status</th>

          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <% int gcount = 0; %>
          <logic:iterate id="row" scope="request" name="dnr.mo.gov.permits.permittedFeatureList" property="permittedFeatureList" >
            <% if( gcount % 2 == 0 ) { %>
              <tr class="rowaltcolor">
            <% } else { %>
              <tr bgcolor="white">                                  
            <% } %> 
              <td align="center">
                <html:link action="/permit/permittedFeatureBasic" paramId="permittedFeatureId"
                    paramName="row" paramProperty="permittedFeatureId">
                  <bean:write name="row" property="permittedFeatureNum" />
                </html:link>
              </td>
              <td align="center">
                <bean:write name="row" property="mgpPermittedFeatureNum" />
              </td>
              <td align="center">
                <logic:equal name="row" property="isActive" value="Yes">
                  <label for="Permitted Feature ${row.selectedPrimaryId}" class="hidden">Primary Indicator</label>
                  <html:radio idName="row" value="permittedFeatureId" property="selectedPrimaryId" styleId="Permitted Feature ${row.selectedPrimaryId}"/>
                </logic:equal>
                <logic:notEqual name="row" property="isActive" value="Yes">
                  <label for="Permitted Feature ${row.selectedPrimaryId}" class="hidden">Primary Indicator</label>
                  <html:radio idName="row" value="permittedFeatureId" property="selectedPrimaryId" styleId="Permitted Feature ${row.selectedPrimaryId}" disabled="true" />
                </logic:notEqual>
              </td>
              <td align="left">
                <bean:write name="row" property="permittedFeatureTypeDesc" />
              </td>
              <td align="center">
                <bean:write name="row" property="isActive" />
              </td>
              <td align="center">
                <bean:write name="row" property="isComplete" />
              </td>
              <td align="center">
                <bean:write name="row" property="isMapped" />
              </td>
              <td align="center">
                <bean:write name="row" property="permittedFeatureTraceStatus" />
              </td>
            </tr>
            <% gcount++; %>
          </logic:iterate>
        </tbody>
      </table>

    <%} %>

      <logic:notEqual scope="request" name="pfHeader" property="permitStatus" value="Terminated" >
      <logic:notEqual scope="request" name="pfHeader" property="permitStatus" value="Retired" >
        <DNRTags:AccessRoles roleList="System Administrator, Permit 1, Permit 2">
          <html:submit value="Save Changes" alt="Save Changes"
              property="action" styleClass="button" 
              onmouseover="this.className='button buttonhov'" 
              onmouseout="this.className='button'"   />
        </DNRTags:AccessRoles>
      </logic:notEqual>
      </logic:notEqual>
      <logic:equal scope="request" name="pfHeader" property="permitStatus" value="Draft" >
        <DNRTags:AccessRoles roleList="Permit 3">
          <html:submit value="Save Changes" alt="Save Changes"
              property="action" styleClass="button" 
              onmouseover="this.className='button buttonhov'" 
              onmouseout="this.className='button'"   />
        </DNRTags:AccessRoles>
      </logic:equal>
    </logic:present>
      <logic:notEqual scope="request" name="pfHeader" property="permitStatus" value="Terminated" >
      <logic:notEqual scope="request" name="pfHeader" property="permitStatus" value="Retired" >
        <DNRTags:AccessRoles roleList="System Administrator, Permit 1, Permit 2">
          <%if(gpcfFlag == false){ %>
            <logic:equal scope="request" name="pfHeader" property="isCafo" value="Y" >
              <html:submit value="Add CAFO Permitted Feature" alt="Add CAFO Permitted Feature" 
                  property="action" styleClass="button" 
                  onmouseover="this.className='button buttonhov'" 
                  onmouseout="this.className='button'" />
            </logic:equal>
            <html:submit value="Add Permitted Feature" alt="Add Permitted Feature" 
                property="action" styleClass="button" 
                onmouseover="this.className='button buttonhov'" 
                onmouseout="this.className='button'" />
          <% }%>
        </DNRTags:AccessRoles>
      </logic:notEqual>
      </logic:notEqual>
      <logic:equal scope="request" name="pfHeader" property="permitStatus" value="Draft" >
        <DNRTags:AccessRoles roleList="Permit 3">
          <%if(gpcfFlag == false){ %>
            <logic:equal scope="request" name="pfHeader" property="isCafo" value="Y" >
              <html:submit value="Add CAFO Permitted Feature" alt="Add CAFO Permitted Feature" 
                  property="action" styleClass="button" 
                  onmouseover="this.className='button buttonhov'" 
                  onmouseout="this.className='button'" />
            </logic:equal>
            <html:submit value="Add Permitted Feature" alt="Add Permitted Feature" 
                property="action" styleClass="button" 
                onmouseover="this.className='button buttonhov'" 
                onmouseout="this.className='button'" />
          <% }%>
        </DNRTags:AccessRoles>
      </logic:equal>
    </div>

      <logic:equal scope="request" name="dnr.mo.gov.permits.permittedFeatureList" property="refreshJspPage" value="true" >
        <META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="30">
      </logic:equal>

    </html:form>
```

Comment: This is a non-standard mechanism. Use something standard.

Comment: Are you saying `<% response.setIntHeader("Refresh",10); %>` is non-standard?  What would be a standard mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

```
response.setHeader("Refresh", "3"); 
response.setIntHeader("Refresh", 3);
```

both are working. So, problem is in your *lots-of-code* block maybe. Are you modifying `response` prior to this line?

**Alternative:(Not Recomended)**

*Your JSP or HTML*

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="<%Variables.refreshTime%>">
```

*Create a Variables class that hold public static variables:*

```
public class Variables{
    public static String refreshTime = "60";
}
```

*Then, you can just update it from anywhere in your code, for e.g.*

```
Variables.refreshTime = "120";   //effects after page reload, same as setIntHeader()
```

Comment: I don't think so.  The only other place `response` is used on the jsp page is when it is passed to a java function and the function does not use it.  (I didn't write the jsp code but I have to modify it.)  Is there a way to modify response without using the `response` variable?

Comment: Nope. Response is not a variable. It is an object required to access methods of HttpResponse class. If its not personal, please share complete code

Comment: That is what I ended up doing (see the original question right before the edit) but I wanted to know why the java code did not work.

Comment: please check alternative in the edited answer, i am sorry i was not able to trace the actual problem from the code.