# How to auto refresh a page using servlet and jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

once I deleted a form in chrome and then i goes to mozilla with the same form without refreshing a page and adding an element,Exception occurs How to solve this issue?

Comment: You can do `response.setIntHeader("Refresh", 5);` using jsp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to refresh the jsp page after a given time(or interval)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29741026/how-to-refresh-the-jsp-page-after-a-given-timeor-interval)

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript:

```
window.location.reload();
```

in HTML (where 1 = 1 second):

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1">
```